# Rails not Caching Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running Rails 5.2.2 in development mode with caching turned on with the following command: `rails dev:cache`. In development.rb, I have the following code which came in the file by defaut:

```
if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```

I have verified that the condition succeeds, but when I check the headers of my `applicaton.js` and `application.css` files the `Cache-Control` header has the following value: `Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate`. Can someone please provide some guidance as to what I am doing wrong? Everything I have read claims that this configuration should work.

**UPDATE**

So it appears that this code properly caches files that I have in my `/public` which makes sense given the method name, but I thought this was supposed to cache the assets in my actual asset pipeline but it does not. The documentation I've read indicates that it should. I've tried running the following commands in an attempt to make sure everything was properly reset:

```
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile
rails server
```